# Looking for the mac os resource definition for the 'styl' resource

Tags: macos, resources, deprecated

I have searched the net for this antiquated piece of Mac OS 9 technology and actually have a need of it for current Mac OS X development.

I can not find a .r definition in the current set of Mac OS X SDKs.

Effectively I need to be able to analyse and create a styl resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'styl'` resource contains the same structure used by TextEdit (the ancient TextEdit, not the current TextEdit.app) when copying styled text to the clipboard. It is always used in tandem with a corresponding plain text buffer. See [this tech note](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/te/te_525.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10002840).

This corresponds to `struct StScrpRec` in TextEdit.h. You can find this file at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/TextEdit.h`. Note that there are not necessarily 1601 elements in the `ScrpSTTable`: it's a variable length array, whose actual length is given by the `scrpNStyles` member of `StScrpRec`.